Error Installing Putty
I get this error when I try to install Putty. I was following this guide. How can I fix it?
-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install -y putty
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec58 : Depends: libcodec2-1.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libdav1d5 (>= 0.2.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libmfx1 (>= 18.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                Depends: libx264-163 (>= 2:0.163.3060+git5db6aa6) but it is not installable
 libavfilter7 : Depends: libmfx1 (>= 18.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libavformat58 : Depends: libsrt1.4-gnutls (>= 1.4.4) but it is not installable
 libavutil56 : Depends: libmfx1 (>= 18.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 packettracer : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installable
 putty : Depends: putty-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


This question is similar to: How do I enable the "Universe" repository?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Picking two packages in your list show putty-tools | 0.81-1                      | noble/universe           | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x and libmfx1 | 22.5.4-1        | noble/universe    | amd64   so you've either NOT enabled universe OR not actually updated your software lists  (you've not mentioned architecture as that can also be a problem as per my details; but I'm assuming amd64)

I don't see a package for noble/universe  in my list. I don't know what this is, or how it's relevant.

This question is similar to: How do I restore the default repositories?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My comment only refers to the putty-tools and libmfx1 packages which were taken from your question; universe is a repository those packages are found in for the noble release (noble being the codename for 24.04; and I got noble from your tagging 24.04)... the detail I put in code tags was from a CLI enquiry based on details in your question; though you could also use https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and a web browser too etc (I just prefer command/CLI over browser....)

I just updated to 24.04 the day before. I got a message immediately after asking this question that a further parital update was required. Since finishing the update, I installed putty per instructions from the web with no problems.
